# vscode-ripgrep not getting installed in VSCode build/run process

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

I was trying to build and run VSCode on my Ubuntu 17.10 using the following guide: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#build-and-run
When I tried to install dependencies using yarn, it is giving me the following error:

`error /home/dhairyakhale/git/vscode/node_modules/vscode-ripgrep: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node ./lib/postinstall.js
Arguments: 
Directory: /home/dhairyakhale/git/vscode/node_modules/vscode-ripgrep
Output:
Unzipping to /home/dhairyakhale/git/vscode/node_modules/vscode-ripgrep/bin`

And then it stops the process. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue while installing Theia. The broken vscode-ripgrep installation caused it. Here is the ticket I submitted to vscode-ripgrep.
https://github.com/roblourens/vscode-ripgrep/issues/15